# How can I get rid of rectangular TextView in AlertDialog?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-alertdialog

So I'm trying to make an alert dialog as a circle, but I can't force `TextView` to be the same shape. It always has square borders. [square outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G7jE.png) / [dialog phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHq4u.png).
Should I use another view? Or I simply cant do it?
My `XML` for `TextView`: [xml textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl1I7.png)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/expressionTextView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/correct_answer"
    android:drawableTint="@color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/oval_background"

    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="110dp"
    android:paddingBottom="110dp"
    android:text="@string/youWin"
    android:elevation="30dp"

    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

I'm trying to launch alert dialog from fragment, so here is Kotlin code:

```
 val dialogBinding = AlertDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity).apply {
        setCancelable(true)
        setView(dialogBinding.root)
    }.create()
    dialog.show()
```

Comment: All views are rectangular.  But unless you draw an outline around them, it shouldn't matter.  Just make sure your content fits in the circle and the user won't know that the view is square-  all they'll see is text on a circle.  Just make sure your circle background uses a transparent color for the part outside the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This white part is not related to the `TextView` but to the background of the dialog window; android dialogs have separate window than the main application window.

So, to fix it you need to apply a transparent background to the dialog window itself using `window.setBackgroundDrawable()`:

```
val dialogBinding = AlertDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity).apply {
    setCancelable(true)
    setView(dialogBinding.root)
}.create().apply {
        window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, android.R.color.transparent, null))
    }
dialog.show()
```

Note: I am assuming that you already using a transparent background drawable in `oval_background.xml`; this is a one if you yours didn't work:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#25C651" />
</shape>
```

[image]